# Getting the Count of records without GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table like this

```
Id  TagNo  F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F11 CoreNo
 1   1000   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    1
 2   1000   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    2
 3   1000   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    3
 4   1001   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    1
 5   1001   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    2
```

I want to have

```
  TagNo  F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F11 CoreNo TotalCores
   1000   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    1       3
   1000   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    2
   1000   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    3
   1001   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    1       2
   1001   A  B  C  D  E  F  R  E W   W   D    2
```

The value for columns F1... F11 (which actually are more than that) are not important.

I know about `Count()`. But if I want to use `Count()` then I have to group by all the columns, which I don't want .

I hope that I could make it clear

Thank you

Comment: That's like wanting to eat, but not wanting food. What will you eat?

Comment: for having count() , do I have to group by all fields?

Comment: No. You have to group by the fields for which you want to split your count by, e.g. CoreNo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT
    TagNo, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, CoreNo,
    TotalCores = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY TagNo)
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: Ha ha. Clever. Dumb question, but clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do a sub-select with group by in the sub select.  Not a great idea though if its a big table.

Answer (score -1):

Without GROUP BY and COUNT :-)

```
select *, 
  (select max(coreno) from table t2 where t1.tagno=t2.tagno and t1.coreno=1) TotalCores 
from table t1
```